# GCP - Cloud Run : "Error: The user is forbidden from accessing the bucket"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I am writing a GitHub Action to deploy my application to GCP's "Cloud Run" service.

```yaml
name: Deploy to production

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  PROJECT_ID: XXX
  SERVICE_NAME: XXX
  RUN_REGION: XXX
  PACKAGE_VERSION : XXX

permissions:
  contents: read
  id-token: write

jobs:
  deployment-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v0
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: XXX
          service_account: XXX
      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0
        with:
          service: ${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}
          source: gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }} # equivalent to "gcloud builds submit ..."
          region: ${{ env.RUN_REGION }}
          tag: ${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
```

I run into this error :

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) The user is forbidden from accessing the bucket [XXX]. Please check your organization's policy or if the user has the "serviceusage.services.use" permission
```

I tried to add this permission to my service account but I am still running on the same error :

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding XXX --member=serviceAccount:XXX --role=roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin
```

I set up the Workload Identity Federation from this [tutorial](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#setup).

Comment: Try adding: storage.objects.get and storage.buckets.get roles to the service account.

Comment: Looks like a permission issue based on the error. This [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-to-resources#granting_permissions_to_run_gcloud_commands) might help then please list the permission of the account you are using and add it to your post as it can help identify the problem.

Comment: Give the role storage object admin to your service account. To deploy your code, the code must be uploaded to Cloud Storage and then build with Cloud Build. If you can't access the bucket, you can't run the build.

Comment: I have the same problem with GitLab and none of the solutions above work. Despite the fact that I granted the necessary rights to the service account linked to my Workload Identity Pool, it does not work. When using Workload Identity Federation, it creates a new project that we cannot manipulate.

Answer (score 5):

Grant **Storage Admin** role to the service account instead of **Storage Object Admin** to allow your Github Action to deploy using the workflow template.

I had this error when setting up Workload Identity to a Github Action. The error message is weird but the issue is in the workflow template. The template instructs you to grant **Storage Objects Admin**, but from the [required permissions page](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code#permissions_required_to_deploy) also linked in the template, it says we need to grant **Storage Admin**.

You may need to also grant the **Service Usage Consumer** role; I had it already so I'm not sure if it is required.

Comment: I tried your solution but still not working with me

Comment: @huykon225: what error is shown to you? It should work as long as the service account has the permissions listed on the documentation page I linked.

Comment: I came across the same problem and this was indeed the solution that got it working. The workflow template is incorrect and definitely misleads you.